# ggplot2 trying to make repeated stacked area graph; getting inconsistent errors

Tags: r, ggplot2

As part of a much bigger script, I have to make 70 stacked area graphs, 1 for each year, and I write them to a pdf. I am having problems only *sometimes*. I have it set up as a loop, and sometimes it breaks in the first four years, sometimes it gets halfway through, sometimes almost to the end.

When I step through the loop for whichever year it broke (by uncommenting the ThisYear and window lines), I can get the graph to appear in a window just fine.  *Sometimes*.  Sometimes I'll graph the same year twice and the first time it works and the second time is doesn't.  And sometimes it's vice versa.

The errors, when they occur, are either "Error: Results must be all atomic, or all data frames", or "Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1464, 1458", or "Error: cannot have attributes on a CHARSXP" but I can't make the same error re-occur reliably.  They happen when it gets to print(p), but I can't figure out what about "p" is making it crash.

The data that I am using (faked up as "BlueData", "GreenData", "YellowData" and "SalmonData" below) is all doubles, I have checked and rechecked.  No NAs.  In fact, when I faked the data up to post this here, I thought I had something, because it wasn't crashing.  Then I ran it several times, and it too started throwing the same errors in the same inconsistent way.

Edit: I'm probably missing some "require" statements... I'll fix soon.

```
require(lubridate)

TestYear = 1929

BlueLimit = 110

### creating fake data to mimic what my data is like

BlueData <- rnorm(70*365+14, mean = 100, sd = 25)
BlueData <- ifelse(BlueData > BlueLimit, BlueLimit, BlueData)
YellowData <- rnorm(70*365+14, mean = 15, sd = 2)
SalmonData <- rnorm(70*365+14, mean = 20, sd = 3)
GreenData <- rnorm(70*365+14, mean = 5, sd = 1)
BigData.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(BlueData,YellowData,SalmonData,GreenData))
BigData.df$Date <- seq(from = ISOdate(TestYear - 1, 10, 1), length.out = nrow(BigData.df), by = "day")
BigData.df$MainData <- BigData.df$BlueData + BigData.df$GreenData + BigData.df$YellowData + BigData.df$SalmonData
BigData.df$LimitData <- BlueLimit

### long complicated reasons, but no February 29ths allowed in the dataset...

BigData.df <- subset(BigData.df, (month(BigData.df$Date) == 2)*(day(BigData.df$Date) == 29) == 0)

### okay, that should do it for mocking up data...

pdfFilename <- "C:\\TestFolder\\TestPDF.pdf"


plot_colors_aggregate = c("gold","forestgreen","lightsalmon","dodgerblue")


    ### establish appropriate scale for top of graph and gridlines

max_y <- max(BigData.df$MainData)
max_y <- ceiling(max_y/50)*50
if (max_y <= 200) {
    gridline_multiplier = 20 
    } else {
    gridline_multiplier = 50
}




pdf(file = pdfFilename, height=8, width = 11, onefile = TRUE)


for (ThisYear in 1929:1998){

    #GraphYear = TestYear
    #windows(height = 8, width = 12)

    cat("\t\tNow working on",ThisYear)

    page_title = paste("This Graph is for",ThisYear)

    ##### CREATE SUBSET OF BIGDATA.DF WITH JUST THIS GRAPH YEAR

    GraphData.df <- subset(BigData.df, year(BigData.df$Date) == ThisYear)


    ##### CREATE SMALLER DF WITH JUST DATA TO BE GRAPHED

    df4plot <- data.frame(
                    AllColors = c(GraphData.df$BlueData, 
                            GraphData.df$SalmonData, 
                            GraphData.df$GreenData, 
                            GraphData.df$YellowData),
                    date = rep(GraphData.df$Date, 4),
                    DataType = rep(c("Blue Stuff", "Salmon Stuff", "Green Stuff", "Yellow Stuff"), each = 365)
                    )


    df4LimitLine <- data.frame(
                    BlueLimit = GraphData.df$LimitData,
                    date = GraphData.df$Date
                    )



    df4plot$DataType <- factor(df4plot$DataType, 
                levels = c("Yellow Stuff", "Green Stuff","Salmon Stuff","Blue Stuff"))


    #PeriodBreaks <- GraphData.df$Date[FirstOfTheMonth.v]   



    scale_color_manual(values=plot_colors_aggregate)


    p <- ggplot(data = df4plot, aes(date, AllColors)) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = plot_colors_aggregate) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = plot_colors_aggregate)+ 
        scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max_y), breaks=seq(0,max_y,gridline_multiplier*2))


    p <- p + 
        geom_area(aes(colour = DataType, fill = DataType), position="stack")  +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0, vjust=1)) + 
        theme(legend.position=c(.7, .7), legend.title=element_blank(), legend.justification = "left", legend.background = element_rect(fill="white")) +
        theme(panel.background = element_rect(), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "darkgrey", linetype = "dotted"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="lightgrey", linetype = "dotted")) +
        theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,5,1),"line"))

    p <- p + geom_line(data=df4LimitLine, aes(x=date,y=BlueLimit, linetype = "Limit of Blue Data") ,colour="darkblue") +
        theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill="white", linetype = 0)) +
        scale_linetype_manual(name = "Linetype", values = "dashed") +
        annotate("text", x=df4LimitLine$date[floor(nrow(df4LimitLine)/2)], y=max_y, label=page_title) 



    print(p)

    grid.text("Blah blah blah", x=unit(.95,"npc"), y=unit(.1,"npc"), hjust=1, gp=gpar(cex = .8))
    grid.text("Yadda yadda yadda", x=unit(.95,"npc"),y=unit(.08,"npc"), hjust = 1, gp=gpar(cex = .8))

    cat(ThisYear,"now finished.\n")
}


dev.off()
```

Comment: The message about a differing number of rows is likely caused by the way you are creating `df4plot` - you would get this error any time a year doesn't have exactly 365 days of data.  Consider reshaping the dataset using functions from `reshape2` or `tidyr` to avoid this problem.  I couldn't reproduce any of the other error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the inconsistent errors and Error: Results must be all atomic, or all data frames by reverting to R 3.1.1.  It seems 3.2.0 is unstable.